# Android studio cannot resolve any symbol

Tags: android, xml

None of the components I add on layout .xml are detected on the .java code. 
I'm an absolute beginner trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.androidauthority.com/lets-build-a-simple-text-editor-for-android-773774/

So, this must be something really stupid haha

I've tried: *restarting android studio*, *cleaning the project*, *rebuilding the project*, *invalidating caches*, *re-importing the project*, *deleting the .iml file and the .idea folder*.

My code... it must be pretty much the same as in the tutorial except for the variable name, but here it goes:

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.notezinhas;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    String ff = some_textView;
}
```

^ This last line is where the `Cannot resolve symbol 'some_textView'` shows up

**activity_main.xml**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/some_textView"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**the logcat!**

```
2019-04-03 23:52:33.075 9866-9992/? E/TransactionsProtoFiller: Client token done future failed
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Throwable: Account is null
        at com.google.common.r.a.d.b(SourceFile:107)
        at com.google.common.r.a.d.get(SourceFile:81)
        at com.google.common.r.a.da.a(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.common.r.a.bf.a(SourceFile:28)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.google.e.a.b(SourceFile:18)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.google.e.a.a(SourceFile:8)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.h.a.a(SourceFile:81)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.h.b.c.a(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.n.a.d.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.common.r.a.cx.b(SourceFile:9)
        at com.google.common.r.a.bs.run(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.common.r.a.cw.run(SourceFile:7)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.g.run(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.be.run(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.be.run(SourceFile:3)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:914)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.l.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Account is null
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.fl.d.a(SourceFile:6)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.google.e.a.b(SourceFile:16)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.google.e.a.a(SourceFile:8) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.h.a.a(SourceFile:81) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.h.b.c.a(Unknown Source:8) 
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.n.a.d.a(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.common.r.a.cx.b(SourceFile:9) 
        at com.google.common.r.a.bs.run(SourceFile:5) 
        at com.google.common.r.a.cw.run(SourceFile:7) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.g.run(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.be.run(SourceFile:3) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.be.run(SourceFile:3) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:914) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.b.l.run(SourceFile:6)
```

Have you seen this problem before? What should I do?

Comment: Share your logcat, please. And please, pay attention, Android (the code, the app) is one thing, Android Studio (IDE) is another, very different. Your question is about the first.

Comment: @statosdotcom I've been trying to get the logcat since you posted this, because it just says there are no debuggable processes :( Seems there are a lot of problems with my android studio. I think the problem is android studio.. but this is my first app aaaaahh x(

I'll get back to you when I get the logcat!

Comment: Hey! ahah... don't worry. AS is not easy to configure, indeed. LogCat is just a small window that uses to be at the bottom of the IDE. It is showed by changing the current tab window. There you have options for it to display all messages/error messages/system messages and so on. Select only "error messages" and run your app. Then logcat can be helpful. Luck and keep coding!

Comment: @statosdotcom I got the emulator working, yay! But I can't get a logcat because if I uncomment the error line ( String ff = some_textView; ) , it does't compile or show the app :/

Comment: This is exactelly where logcat helps. When your compiling breaks, logcat shows why is breaking. Go go go

Comment: @statosdotcom haha thank you for all your help and enthusiasm! This is not my main project at the moment, so I just got the logcat now.. Updating the question :D

Comment: Hey, it's nice to see things going ;) did not paid too much attention but is strange. Error says "account is null"... waw. Maybe u r using some google drive account or library... i don't know. One try could be to strip away pieces of code, trying to put things simpler, demanding less resources and third parties (external) to compile. An try to run again. Have a look a your `build` files, they may be asking something different. Let's wait for a clue from the community. Later you say to me what is notezinhas eheh.

Comment: @statosdotcom Yes, strange x( Especially because I did nothing else except create the components in the design and try to use them in the code smh. I'll take a look at the build file.. and wait! Thanks for the help again ^^ When I finish notezinhas I'll let you know haha!

Answer (score 0):

-_- To anyone who might see this:

- **Make sure you only access the components after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`** (in this case, I was trying to get it outside of the methods in the mainActivity class)
- **Get the right type of variable** (I was trying to use the String type for a TextView)

Other things I did to get it working:

- Get graddle off offline mode
- Run a random git project, which installed a bunch of stuff I probably don't need. This was to make sure my Android Studio wasn't crazy, haha! But it could've been a factor on getting it running